# Parametrize a surface using cylindrical coord.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric

[image]

Hi!

I am having trouble parametrizing this tower. Specifically the radius which has to be a function of the height $Z$

$$0<z<H, 0 ≤ r ≤ R(2 − z/H), \quad 0<\theta<2\pi$$

I do not understand how they found the radius inequalities. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: R is a function of z. Determine R(z) and you got half of your parametrization

Comment: Project onto just the y-z plane and look at the edge of your shape. It just forms a straight line. On that plane, z is the height, and r is y.

Answer (score 0):

$r$ will be a linear function of $z$, if the sides are straight, so the limit for $r$ will be in the form $0<r<az+b$. You can find the constants $a$ and $b$ knowing the slope/intercept of the straight line sides of the tower.

Comment: Can you please provide a detailed explanation! :) thanks